# Poisson bivector on the product of two manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be two manifolds. Let $(U, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $(V, y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ local coordinates of $X, Y$ respectively. A Poisson bivector on $X$ is defined by 
\begin{align}
\pi_X = \sum_{i,j} \{x_i, x_j\} \partial_{x_i} \wedge \partial_{x_j},
\end{align}
where $\{,\}$ is a Poisson bracket on $C^{\infty}(X)$. Similarly, we have a Poisson bivector on $Y$:
\begin{align}
\pi_Y = \sum_{i,j} \{y_i, y_j\} \partial_{y_i} \wedge \partial_{y_j},
\end{align}
where $\{,\}$ is a Poisson bracket on $C^{\infty}(Y)$.
My question is: how to define $\pi_{X \times Y}$? I think that a local coordinate on $X 
\times Y$ is $(U \times V, x_1 \otimes y_1, \ldots, x_n \otimes y_m)$. Maybe 
\begin{align}
\pi_{X \times Y} = \sum_{i,j,s,t} \{ x_i \otimes y_j, x_s \otimes y_t \} \partial_{x_i \otimes y_j} \wedge \partial_{x_s \otimes y_t}.
\end{align}

But I don't know how to compute $\partial_{x_i \otimes y_j}$. Are there some relation between $\pi_X$, $\pi_Y$ and $\pi_{X \times Y}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The local coordinates on $U\times V$ are just $x_1,\ldots,x_n;y_1,\ldots ,y_m) $ so the Poisson bivector is $\pi _X+\pi _Y$.

Comment: @abx, thank you very much. I think that it depends on the Poisson bracket on $C^{\infty}(X \times Y)$. If we define $\{f_1 \otimes g_1, f_2 \otimes g_2\} = \{f_1, f_2\} \otimes g_1g_2 + f_1 f_2 \otimes \{g_1, g_2\}$, then $\pi_{X \times Y} = \pi_X + \pi_Y$. I think that in general, they can be different.

Comment: Of course there are tons of Poisson brackets on a manifold! I just say that there is a notion of products of Poisson manifolds, given by $\pi_X+\pi_Y$. Anyway, this site is for mathematics questions at research level. Please consider using math.stackexchange instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the Poisson product manifold of $(X,\pi_X)$ and $(Y,\pi_Y)$ is the manifold
$$(X\times Y,\pi_X+\pi_Y).$$
For a reference, see for example *Lectures on the geometry of Poisson manifolds* by Izu Veisman.